# Map returns a list of all None

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to write a simple python code which would find a list k nearest elements to origin using a max heap. My main question is around the usage of the map in python, I tried to code it in this way, and I am getting a list of `None`s as output whereas I was expecting max_heap to be populated with values pushed by heappush/heappushpop. Can someone point what's wrong here? Also, I am wondering if I really need to declare max_heap empty list? Is there a way in which I can write this entire logic in 1 statement? Thanks!

```py
def find_closest_k_nums(nums, k):
    max_heap = []
    for num in nums:
        if len(max_heap) == k + 1:
            heapq.heappushpop(max_heap, -num)
        else:
            heapq.heappush(max_heap, -num), nums
    return [-s for s in heapq.nlargest(k, max_heap)]
# >>> find_closest_k_nums([1, 5, 6, 3, 8, 9, 10], 4) => [1, 3, 5, 6]

# I tried to write the above function using map but I got an empty list.
def find_closest_k_nums_with_map(nums, k):
    max_heap = []
    map(lambda x: heapq.heappushpop(max_heap, -x)
        if len(max_heap) == k + 1 else heapq.heappush(max_heap, -x), nums)
    return [-s for s in heapq.nlargest(k, max_heap)]
# >>> find_closest_k_nums_with_map([1, 5, 6, 3, 8, 9, 10], 4) => []
```

Comment: `map` creates an iterable. You actually have to iterate over it for anything to happen, and you need to save the result unless you are relying on side-effects.

Comment: I have tried that, it gives me the same result. Thanks though!

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything except define a class and a function, please provide a [mcve]. In any case, you should never use map for side-effects. It is simply bad style

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated my code with a minimal reproducible example. I agree that I am kind of relying on side effects rather than the actual map's output which is not a great style of coding, but I am just trying to play around with maps a little bit and trying to explore how maps work. I am particularly confused here as the side effect should populate the `max_heap` but it isn't doing. Am I missing something?

Comment: *Don't* use a map solely for the side effect of its function. Use a `for` loop instead. You are never iterating over the resulting `map` object, so the function is never applied to each element of `nums`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` returns an iterable which calls the function *on demand* as you ask for elements from the iterable. More simply:

```
>>> def increment(x):
...   print(f"Calling increment on {x}")
...   return x + 1
...
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = map(increment, x)
```

Until you iterate over `y`, `increment` is never called. Only as you call `next` on `y` does `increment` get called.

```
>>> next(y)
Calling increment on 1
2
>>> next(y)
Calling increment on 2
3
```

In order for the elements of `nums` to be added to your heap in the your second function, you need to (somehow) iterate over the elements that `map` will yield. For example, pass the `map` object to `list` to force iteration:

```
def find_closest_k_nums_with_map(nums, k):
    max_heap = []
    list(map(lambda x: heapq.heappushpop(max_heap, -x)
        if len(max_heap) == k + 1 else heapq.heappush(max_heap, -x), nums))
    return [-s for s in heapq.nlargest(k, max_heap)]
```

But this is *terrible* style. You aren't actually interested in the return value of the function getting mapped over `nums`, only its side effect of updating `max_heap`. When that is the case, just use a `for` loop as in your first function.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation, what I learned:
1. Never use maps when we don't care about the returned iterator and we are just worried about the side effects.
2. The maps evaluate in a lazy way and need to be iterated so that the function inside the map is actually invoked.